# How to specify DPDK driver using EAL option when using shared libraries?

Tags: dpdk

I understand that when compiling DPDK with CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=y, the driver must be explicitly set with the '-d' EAL option.

I am using an Intel X722 NIC.  What should my '-d' EAL option be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK eal argument for the shared library is passed with the option `-d`. For your specific NIC you would need to pass `-d librte_pmd_i40e.so`.

Please note since your application or makefile is not shared, I assume you would end up passing libraries for mempool, ring, call, hash and others too.

Comment: Thanks, I added -d librte_pmd_i40e.so and the ports are now detected. However, rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() then fails, which I guess is related to your second point.

Comment: I tried "-d librte_mempool.so" (including path), but that did not fix it. I linked my application to a shared dpdk library that includes all the usual libs, do I need to specify lots of libraries again as parameters? How can I determine which ones?

Comment: if you check with `ldd [target bianry]`, you would mostly find `librte_mbuf.so.4.1 => not found librte_ethdev.so.11.1 => not found librte_mempool.so.5.1 => not found librte_eal.so.9.1 => not found`. If this is true, you have export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to where the dpdpdk shared libraries are present. While running your target application, you might encounter `MBUF: error setting mempool handler EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1 Cause: Cannot create mbuf pool`. If yes, run with `-d librte_pmd_i40e.so -d librte_mempool_ring.so`

Comment: Thanks, but ldd shows no 'not found messages'.

Also, -d librte_pmd_i40e.so -d librte_mempool_ring.so didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @DavidA I have already updated in the answer `Please note since your application or makefile is not shared, I assume you would end up passing libraries for mempool, ring, call, hash and others too.`. Using DPDK exaqmple makefile for shared libraries `-d librte_pmd_i40e.so -d librte_mempool_ring.so`. if you want quick debug, please reach me overskype or chat

Comment: Thanks, with respect, I don't see how your latest comment helps as my previous comment shows that I have tried those '-d' options. I am going to switch to the static library route as that seems easier.

Comment: Hi @DavidA with respect, I have not modified anything in my answer. I had already shared the answer with the caution (`since you are not sharing Makefile`) I assume you will end up with more libraries to add in compile and eal args. Hence if you want me to look at please feel free to reach over skype

Comment: Understood. Thank you.